In triangle ABC, $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C ≤ 1$. Prove that $\min\{A + B, B + C, C + A\} < 30°$.

In triangle ABC, $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C ≤ 1$. Prove that  $\min\{A + B, B + C, C + A\} < 30°$.

I know that A is greater than 150° and the sum of B and C is less than 30°, but I have no idea of how to actually prove it. I asked different people but they all told me that there should be a formula for this but they don't remember it.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Can you please tell me how you found out A>150°? It will be of great help

WLOG, assume that $a \leq b \leq c$, so that $A\leq B \leq C$ and $\min\{A+B,A+C,B+C\}=A+B$. Next, if $30^{\circ}<B<90^{\circ}$, $\sin{B}>\frac{1}{2}$, forcing $\sin{C}<\frac{1}{2}$. This implies that $C>150^{\circ}$, and $C+B$ would exceed $180^{\circ}$. Certainly $B$ cannot be obtuse, because that would cause $B$ to be the largest angle. Thus, that leaves us with $0<B \leq 30^{\circ}$. By the presumed inequality, $0<A\leq 30^{\circ}$. Therefore, $C$ must be obtuse.
Next, for the sake of contradiction, let $30^{\circ} \leq A+B \leq 60^{\circ}$. That leaves us with $120^{\circ} \leq C \leq 150^{\circ}$ and $\sin{C} \geq \frac{1}{2}$. One could verify using the function $f(x,y)=\sin{x}+\sin{y}$ and the domain $\frac{\pi}{6}<x+y<\frac{\pi}{3} \land 0 \leq x,y \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$ that the smallest value $f(x,y)$ can have is $\frac{1}{2}$, happening only when one of the angles is $0$.
Therefore, we conclude that $A+B<30^{\circ}$, as desired.

WLOG, assume $A \leq B \leq C$, then $0 < A \leq 60^\circ \leq C.$ Suppose $C \leq 90^\circ$, then $B \geq (180^\circ - C)/2 \geq 45^\circ$. Therefore
$$\sin A + \sin B + \sin C \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} > 1$$
which is contradiction. Thus, $C > 90^\circ$. We have
$$\sin A + \sin B = 2 \sin \frac{B+A}{2} \cos \frac{B-A}{2} = 2\cos \frac{C}{2}\cos\frac{B-A}{2} $$
Notice that $0 \leq \dfrac{B-A}{2}<\dfrac{180^\circ - C}{2} < 45^\circ$ therefore
$$\begin{align}
\sin A + \sin B &> 2\cos\frac{C}{2}\cos\frac{180^\circ - C}{2}\\[1.5mm]
&= 2 \cos \frac{C}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}\\[1.5mm]
&= \sin C
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$\sin A + \sin B + \sin C > 2 \sin C$$
therefore $\sin C < \dfrac{1}{2}$. Since $ C > 90^\circ$, $C > 150^\circ$
